# Different size texture regions bounce when run as animation in libGDX

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, texturepacker

I have a Texture sheet that was created with a texture packer app, it removes all of the unnecessary  transparent pixels to save space in the final texture sheet. The problem is my animation is a guy with a sword, so when he attacks he swings the sword over his head, meaning it changes the width and height of the sprite. Example...

```
characterAttack1 = new TextureRegion(texture, 863, 979, 152, 149);
//more animation frames...
characterAttack8 = new TextureRegion(texture, 1, 2, 340, 256);
```

As you can see the first frame is 152x149, but by the 8th frame it is now 340x256.
So when the animation runs if I use the normal getWidth() getHeight() methods within my Character class the character will shrink as he attacks, since the height and width of the attack is larger as the sword swings. On the other hand if I use the method...

```
((TextureRegion)AssetLoader.characterAttack.getKeyFrame(runTime)).getRegionWidth();
and 
((TextureRegion)AssetLoader.characterAttack.getKeyFrame(runTime)).getRegionHeight();
```

The character will bounce around the screen when the attack animation is run. I know I can't be the only person that has encountered something like this, but I can't seem to find any information on this. Is my only course of action to repack the texture file and make each one the same width and height even though there will be a ton of transparent pixels in the final packed texture?

If you need to see the AssetLoader and the batcher.draw methods or anything else I am more than happy to provide code samples, I am just trying to keep the post from being too large. Thank you.

Comment: Which texture packer app? LibGDX includes its own texture packer in its tools module that can strip whitespace from the atlas. When loaded in LibGDX as a TextureAtlas, you can retrieve a whole `Array<AtlasRegion>` for each animation all at once to feed into an `Animation<AtlasRegion>` and these contain the offset parameters you need for drawing them. The way you are loading individual TextureRegions with hand-typed numbers looks very painful.

Comment: It is actually called texturepacker from here... https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker
I am trying to learn java game programming so I am attempting to convert an old phaser game I made into java/android/ios and saw libGDX so I am trying it out

Comment: I assume that outputs more than just an image file. It's been years since I used that particular app. I think it had multiple output formats so you could try to choose one that's easy to parse. Then write a simple class that loads that file and creates instances of a TextureRegion wrapper class that also includes offset data to handle the stripped white space. But it would be easier to use LibGDX's texture packer if that app doesn't output LibGDX format. If you don't have the source images, you could use ShoeBox to extract them.

Comment: It has a json file that tells the parser what coordinates the images are at and their height and width. The problem is though, when the character swings the sword the height and width double, so when my character is drawn on screen, if I use the default height and width values he will shrink as he swings the sword, if I use the height and width values for that specific image he will move around the screen since the x and y are always the same number, but the height and width change.

Comment: See if you can export in a format that also includes x and y offsets (the amount of whitespace removed from the left and bottom of the source). If it can't do that I don't see a way to use that particular texture packer and sanely strip the whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are tying to make your game run on something with extremely low RAM, there is really no need to pack the textures so tightly. Sprite sheets are really quite small when you think about the grand scale of things. I imagine your game would require around 100MB of RAM when running, given that most computers now have upwards of 4GB of RAM, what's a few more MB?

A sprite-sheet for your character should be the **maximum** size of any one of the frames. e.g. If the largest frame is 340x256, every frame needs to be that size.

Now the character will be in the same position every frame because the render position will not change.

If the centre of the character is always in the middle of the sprite, you could render from the centre of the image, which would fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, that's kind of what I was thinking, I was just worried and thought there was a way to do it with removing all transparent pixels. I will re-work the sprite sheet so they are all the right size and fix the position of the character. Thank you.